# Android studio no design/text tag when open an existing project

Tags: android-studio

When I open a project from Github, there is no "design/texts" tag on activity_main.xml.
But It exists if I create a new empty one.

How do I fix it? How can I open the project from Github?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a157m.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI0ev.png)

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: delete the original project, and open again from "build.gradly". Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidX has own library on gradle. ([DrawerLayout implemantation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout?hl=en))

You should add `implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"` to your gradle dependencies in your app.

Path is: app > build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    
    //You should write here
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"

}
```

Comment: what are module dependencies?